# Is there a way to smooth closeby text transitions when using jQuery animations (namely drop)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found it a little difficult to word exactly what I was trying to ask, so I just made a fiddle instead. On my website I currently have a button that triggers a jQuery "drop" effect on a hidden div that has some text under it...like so:

```
<div id="toggle"></div>
<p>Some text under the div</p>
```

When the drop happens, my text shoots to the position it's supposed to be in rather than smoothly transitioning.

Code snippet:

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  $("#toggle").toggle("drop", {
    direction: "up"
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
  <div id="toggle"></div>
  <p>Some text under the div</p>
</body>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/42cdxz83/10/

Is there a way to make the text transition/slide smoothly instead of going instantly from one position to the next? Using .slideDown() on the text is awesome, but is obviously tripped up by my "drop" animation. Looking for any way I can stop the jumpy text.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem was due to the fact that you were toggling the `<div>`, which included the paragraph, and expecting both to work separately. Here's an updated JSFiddle with a result I think you'd like: https://jsfiddle.net/42cdxz83/15/

Comment: I like this answer too, an alternate way that also preserves my use of jQuery and doesn't necessarily need any CSS. Actually, it reduces the work on my end heavily. Accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

- When you use toggle, you are removing your `#toggle` element from the
  DOM. That's why your `<p>` element jumps to the top.

---

### Solution:

Instead of using toggle, you can use **CSS transitions** for this, along with the property `transform`.

---

**Code snippet:**

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  $("#toggle").addClass("drop");
  $("#toggle + p").addClass("up");
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: transform 600ms ease-out, opacity 200ms linear;
}
.drop {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
#toggle + p {
  transition: transform 600ms ease-out;
}
.up {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
  <div id="toggle"></div>
  <p>Some text under the div</p>
</body>
```

---

**Notes:**

- The transformation in the Y axis of your `<p>` element should be equal to the `height` of your `#toggle` element multiplied by -1. *(negative value)*

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, that's exactly what I wanted. Now all I have to do is add a few conditionals, some more classes, and I can get it to reappear in the same way. Appreciate it!